Iterate all letters style/font WITHIN a cell from a excel file read by openpyxl
title.
I want to filter my cells by only keeping letters that do not have a strike through, theoratically that means dive down to each letter and inspect its font/strike attribute.
This is what I have done. I see that there a cell.font attribute, but it does not go down to letter level. I have also tried to traverse the content of a cell using cell.value, which seems to be the only way to traverse such object, but it doesn't produce the font attribute either.
The confusion further grows as you may notice in the screenshot below, before the strike through, "Control " is parsed as a str, while after the strike through appear once, its following letters "s Record" is parsed as a rich_text. str does not have a font attribute and therefore this task seems impossible.

any suggestion?

You can open the Workbook using rich_text=True as in wb = load_workbook('foo.xlsx', rich_text=True)  This will allow you to read each textblock in a cell and obtain the strikethrough status. If a cell contains a date for example it will still be read as a datetime value.

For the following Sheet data 

import openpyxl
from openpyxl.cell.rich_text import TextBlock, CellRichText

wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('foo.xlsx', rich_text=True)
ws = wb['Sheet1']

for cell in ws['A']:
    print(f"Row:{cell.row}")
    if isinstance(ws[f'B{cell.row}'], openpyxl.cell.cell.MergedCell):
        print("Merged Cell")
    if isinstance(cell.value, CellRichText):
        for block in cell.value:
            if isinstance(block, TextBlock):
                print(f"Text Value: '{block.text}', Type {type(block)}, Strikethrough: {block.font.strikethrough}")
            else:
                print(f"Text Value: '{block}' Type {type(block)}")

    else:
        print(f"Cell Type {type(cell.value)} Value: '{cell.value}'")
    print("----------------------------")

Output
Row:1
Merged Cell
Text Value: 'Control Status', Type <class 'openpyxl.cell.rich_text.TextBlock'>, Strikethrough: True
Text Value: ' Record', Type <class 'openpyxl.cell.rich_text.TextBlock'>, Strikethrough: None
----------------------------
Row:2
Text Value: 'A' Type <class 'str'>
Text Value: 'B', Type <class 'openpyxl.cell.rich_text.TextBlock'>, Strikethrough: True
Text Value: 'C', Type <class 'openpyxl.cell.rich_text.TextBlock'>, Strikethrough: None
Text Value: 'D', Type <class 'openpyxl.cell.rich_text.TextBlock'>, Strikethrough: True
Text Value: 'E', Type <class 'openpyxl.cell.rich_text.TextBlock'>, Strikethrough: None
Text Value: 'F', Type <class 'openpyxl.cell.rich_text.TextBlock'>, Strikethrough: True
----------------------------
Row:3
Merged Cell
Text Value: 'Control ' Type <class 'str'>
Text Value: 'Status', Type <class 'openpyxl.cell.rich_text.TextBlock'>, Strikethrough: True
Text Value: ' Record', Type <class 'openpyxl.cell.rich_text.TextBlock'>, Strikethrough: None
----------------------------
Row:4
Text Value: 'A', Type <class 'openpyxl.cell.rich_text.TextBlock'>, Strikethrough: True
Text Value: 'BC', Type <class 'openpyxl.cell.rich_text.TextBlock'>, Strikethrough: None
Text Value: 'DE', Type <class 'openpyxl.cell.rich_text.TextBlock'>, Strikethrough: True
Text Value: 'F', Type <class 'openpyxl.cell.rich_text.TextBlock'>, Strikethrough: None
----------------------------
Row:5
Merged Cell
Cell Type <class 'str'> Value: 'Control Status Record'
----------------------------
Row:6
Cell Type <class 'datetime.datetime'> Value: '2022-11-22 00:00:00'
----------------------------
Row:7
Cell Type <class 'float'> Value: '0.1245'
----------------------------
Row:8
Cell Type <class 'float'> Value: '12.25896'
----------------------------
Row:9
Cell Type <class 'int'> Value: '25'
----------------------------


what if i want to check if other types like float, int, or datetime has a strikethrough?

plus i think your code doesnt handle merged cells very well. if you merge two cells, say cellA1 and cellA2, with same text "control status record" and strike through "control status" only, openpyxl will treat the first part as plain text.

@Yuuya Strikethrough is a text effect If the cell value is a number or datetime then it cannot have strikethrough font unless it's changed to text

I don't know what you mean re the comment on merged cells. If cells A1 & B1 are merged and includes the text  "control status record"  with the section  "control status" as strikethrough text. If you read that merge text, i.e. cell A1 then your would (or should) get two TextBlocks; the first containing the text 'control status' with strikethrough font status True and the second containing the text ' Record' with strikethrough font status None.

sry for the confusion, but  whatr i meant was something like "[del]control status [del] record", it appears that in that case, first word of A1, which has a strike through, will be recognized as a str, which doesnt have a font attribute because its an item from cell.value.

and im almost certain that it happens only at cell A1. I tried the same word "[del]control status [del] record" on other cells and they all worked. and it only happens if the first word in the cell has a strike through

I don't know what your are talking about, Whether merged cell or not makes no difference. Whether cell A1 or other makes no difference. If the cell contains Rich Text it will be determined. The first Block without RIchText will be a string and subsequent blocks are all TextBlocks, otherwise all blocks are TextBlocks.  If you get something different, ensure you have the latest version of Openpxl installed. If you think there is a bug then raise it with Openpyxl Development.

Updated example in answer
